# Throwing user defined exception class from dao layer?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, java-ee-6

I am using Spring3 and Hibernate4. I have below interface and classes.

### FetchDao.java

```
public interface FetchDao{
  List<FetchEntity> getOrderList(Integer orderNumber);
}
```

### FetchDaoImpl.java

```
public class FetchDaoImpl implements FetchDao{

   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory; //sessionFactory is injected through spring

   @Override
    public List<FetchEntity> getOrderList(Integer orderNumber) {
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(
                FetchEntity.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("orderNumber", orderNumber));
        return criteria.list();
    }

}
```

Now above configuration works fine without any issues. I have placed them in DAO layer. Above method does not throw any exception. But **is it good practice to throw user defined exception always?** as below:-

### FetchDao.java

```
public interface FetchDao{
  List<FetchEntity> getOrderList(Integer orderNumber) **throws CustomDAOException**;
}
```

### FetchDaoImpl.java

```
public class FetchDaoImpl implements FetchDao{

   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory; //sessionFactory is injected through spring

   @Override
    public List<FetchEntity> getOrderList(Integer orderNumber) **throws CustomDAOException**{
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(
                FetchEntity.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("orderNumber", orderNumber));
        return criteria.list();
    }

}
```

Here `CustomDAOException` is user defined exception.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is good to throw user-defined exception from dao layer,so that your code can get more modularity.

Comment: So while method execution if any runtime exception is thrown then instead of sending the same exception as is it is better to send user defined exception right? Thanks!

Comment: ya,usually the layers(controller,service,dao) should be modular(i.e) loose coupling.so its good that the database exceptions should be in dao layer and communicate to the next layer using User-defined Exception.